# Bioshock Infinite Lutece Statue Transformation

Tags: bioshock-infinite

In the beginning parts of the game, before the action starts, there's a statue of Lutece which transforms.  It completes the transformation faster than I can get to it, so I can't see what it transforms from.  So my question is, what was the statue originally before the shift?

Comment: Is [this](http://youtu.be/YAYiouLObfs) the statue you are talking about?

Comment: Actually, yea!  I know what it is now, but I'd rather not say in a comment as I don't want to spoil it for anyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see a video of the statue changing [here](http://youtu.be/YAYiouLObfs).

> The statue is of the male Lutece transforming into the female.